# How many records could we extract from SOQl query on User object?

Tags: soql, query, user, limits

We are trying to run a SOQl query to extract the profileName and userRoleName corresponding to id's in the given list

```
SELECT Id,profile.name,userrole.name
   FROM User
   WHERE Id in ('1','2','3','4')
```

the maximum number of id's we are expecting to query is 20000 could i do it in a single query or do i need to split into batches and do it if you could please guide on this it would be of great help

we are trying to query the Salesforce api

Comment: You're running a SOQL from where? The answer depends on context.

Comment: @sfdcfox we are calling the salesforce api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be limited to the number of characters in a SOQL where clause ([SOQL Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm)) (4,000), or approximately 180 user Ids per query. Instead, use [retrieve()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_retrieve.htm) to get up to 2,000 records per API call. This will be at least ten times more efficient than a straight SOQL query.

Comment: [doc ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm)